# Sage Pay Server Integration Token System

Tags: php, opayo

I'm using Sage Pay server integration, which i've tested and is working fine - based on one of the PHP dev kits, which i believe are no longer available. I'm trying to use the token system. As per the documentation i've add &CreateToken=1 to the post to the gateway. I've put this through the simulator - however when it comes to the 'Ready to send the notification post' the 'Data to be sent to your notification url' does include a token.

I've looked around but can't find a lot on the token system other than the documentation. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you checked with Sage Pay that tokenisation works with Simulator mode? I know it does in TEST and of course LIVE mode.

Comment: Hi Pablo - yes that was the issue - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simulator does not support Tokens. You need a normal account and use the test servers. Ask that to the support team of SagePay. This was a fact few months ago, I believe it still is.